# I get an HTTP 400 response on a call to a REST method

Tags: http, rest, http-status-code-400

I have a REST service that needs to handle typical CRUD operations. For my Create method, I use HTTP POST to send the object that I need to create. When I try to test my service using Advanced REST Client (it's a very nice Google Chrome Extension), I pass the object by loading the payload from a local XML file. However, I get an HTTP 400 response (Bad request). I have breakpoints on the server side and they are not hit, so it doesn't even get there. I am thinking that my issue is in the XML file, but that one is fairly simple. I can post it here, if anyone is interested in seeing it. In the meantime, how can I figure out what causes this Bad request error? I installed Fiddler, but it does not give me any information either.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

TIA,
Ed

Comment: Showing some code might get some help..

Comment: My "Create" method takes a complex type as an input parameter. The complex type has about 4 or 5 fields, but some of them are not strings (one is an integer and one is a decimal). Could this be the problem? I read that complex types passed through RESTful service methods must have all members of string type. Is this accurate? I will try to change my complex type and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Actually, it is not true - I've seen examples online where the complex type incorporated members of a type other than string. So I am guessing that the issue lies in how I decorate my REST "Create" method with attributes. So far I tried to indicate that the RequestFormat and ResponseFormat should be WebMessageFormat.Xml, but to no avail.

Comment: I actually figured it out. My DataContract class had several properties. One of these properties was a calculated member and it did not have a setter. The serialization process threw an exception when it tried to work with instances of that class. So this appeared to be a RESTful issue, but in reality it was caused by a mistake in a completely different area. Beginner's mistake, I suppose.

I should mention that it was not until I enabled tracing for WCF that I was able to catch the exception.